# Predict best chess move using RNNs

Tags: rnn, word-embeddings, sequence

I am trying to do a project with AI: in which during any certain moment of a chess game i can predict, using a RNN trained on a kaggle dataset, the best possible move that i can make.

I am having issues with the creation of the model. I have cleaned and preprocessed my dataframe and i got left with this dataset:

```
 0   turns                     19629 non-null  int64 
 1   opening_ply               19629 non-null  int64 
 2   winner_black              19629 non-null  int64 
 3   winner_draw               19629 non-null  int64 
 4   winner_white              19629 non-null  int64 
 5   victory_status_draw       19629 non-null  int64 
 6   victory_status_mate       19629 non-null  int64 
 7   victory_status_outoftime  19629 non-null  int64 
 8   victory_status_resign     19629 non-null  int64 
 9   tokenized_moves           19629 non-null  object
 10  opening_eco_A00           19629 non-null  int64 
 11  opening_eco_A40           19629 non-null  int64 
 12  opening_eco_B00           19629 non-null  int64 
 13  opening_eco_B01           19629 non-null  int64 
 14  opening_eco_B20           19629 non-null  int64 
 15  opening_eco_C00           19629 non-null  int64 
 16  opening_eco_C20           19629 non-null  int64 
 17  opening_eco_C41           19629 non-null  int64 
 18  opening_eco_C50           19629 non-null  int64 
 19  opening_eco_D00           19629 non-null  int64 
 20  opening_eco_Other         19629 non-null  int64
```

I have tokenized and padded my tokenized_moves column and split the data:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['tokenized_moves'])
total_words = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['tokenized_moves'])
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences)

X = padded_sequences[:, :-1]
y = padded_sequences[:, 1:]

y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=total_words)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

I am having issues creating the RNN, when fitting the model it crashes on local and on colab(because i am running out of RAM apparently). I need to be sure i did well and i am just running out of resources, or i did not prepare the model or preprocess the data well.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=total_words, output_dim=100, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(total_words, activation='softmax'))
```

My model summary looks like this:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, 221, 100)          396200    
                                                                 
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 221, 100)          80400     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 221, 3962)         400162    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 876762 (3.34 MB)
Trainable params: 876762 (3.34 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

I am not sure where am i failing?

Comment: Hi @user3253067, welcome to the site. Maybe you are loading your whole dataset on the GPU memory at once.

Comment: This sounds like reinforcement learning, as I discuss [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/628141/247274). I’m not sure you’ll get reasonable results trying to shoehorn this into a supervised learning context. I stand by my opening remarks at the link, that it philosophically wrong to predict something that is under your control when you dictate your actions.

Comment: @Dave to be fair i had my doubts about the logic validity of this project. so finally i changed the purpose

Comment: @noe i was working in colab, i don't know if i have options in the loading process, also my dataset is not that big. but i have noticed that the to_categorical method breaks because i was creating the vocab in a messed up way